# Trying to use serverless-offline-sns with @aws-sdk/client-sns v3 but still loading credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-sns, offline

```
import { SNS } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
const sns = new SNS({
  endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4002",
  region: 'ap-southeast-1',
});
    const messageData = {
      Message: "message",
      TopicArn: process.env.SnsTopicArn!,
      MessageDeduplicationId: uuid.v4(),
      MessageGroupId:'group'
  };
 const resp = await sns.publish(messageData);
```

[image]

I am getting this however I am using offline-sns and also seem to be working in v2 of aws-sdk but not in v3

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: What is `offline-sns`? Currently you are only setting a different `endpoint` but that will not stop `SNS` from requiring credentials to talk to it. Try specifying the `credentials` config parameter as well and setting some dummy values.